# Node.js Convert array to array of objects

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material

I have a rest API in Node.js, which outputs an array like:

```js
[["Benni", 24, "Whatever"], ["Paul", 23, "Whatever"]]
```

Now in order to use it for an Angular Material table, I have to put the array in this format:

```typescript
[{name: 'Benni', age: 24, Text: 'Whatever'}, {name: 'Paul', age: 23, Text: 'Whatever'},]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method of an array.

Simply call a map over the array, get the data in order from the array item and return the object you want in the map function.

```js
const arr = [
  ["Benni", 24, "Whatever"],
  ["Paul", 23, "Whatever"]
];

const remapped = arr.map((data) => {
  const [name, age, Text] = data;
  return {
    name,
    age,
    Text,
  };
});

console.log(remapped);
```

Answer (score 1):

pretty easily:

```
let result = inputArr.map( innerArr => {name: innerArr[0], age: innerArr[1], Text: innerArr[2]});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as follows,

```
var data = [[ "Benni" , 24 , "Whatever" ],[ "Paul" , 23 , "Whatever" ]];

var collection = data.slice(); // make a copy
var keys = ["name","age","text"];

collection = collection.map(function (e) {
    var obj = {};

    keys.forEach(function (key, i) {
        obj[key] = e[i];
    });

    return obj;
});
```

collection object will contain the results as follows

```
    [
  {
    "name": "Benni",
    "age": 24,
    "text": "Whatever"
  },
  {
    "name": "Paul",
    "age": 23,
    "text": "Whatever"
  }
]
```

See this for full code : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7s4z893/)